# How to zoom multiple canvas simultaneously in html5?

Tags: javascript, html

I am working in a html5 project. In which i am drawing multiple shapes (e.g. line, rectangle,circle etc) as an individual canvas.

In brief, i have a canvas on which my document is loaded and when i am drawing any shape i am making a new canvas for that particular drawing. But i am in a problem to zoom drawings because we have HTML5 method to zoom a drawing inside a canvas.

i.e.

```
ctx.scale(zoom_value,zoom_Value);
```

I want to zoom drawing with canvas also.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

@Shanky : Your question seems to be a bit unclear at the moment.Can you please elaborate?

If you mean to ask whether it's possible to scale the `canvas` itself without having to redraw the contents,then sorry,you can't. Re-sizing a `canvas`(or even resetting it's dimensions to the same value will clear the `canvas`).

But yes,you can redraw the `canvas` to achieve the zoom effect.

Edit your question to include some more code so that we might be able to help you out!